# www.domain.com not displaying website but www.domain.com/index.php displays it correctly

Tags: php

I have a Php website and I recently renewed the domain and hosting. When I checked www.domain.com it it not displaying website but when I check for www.domain.com/index.php displays it correctly.. what shall I do to make this correct.

Comment: sounds to me like a problem with the web server's default document settings. If you can post more information about your web server setup we could help more

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code. Your hosting application does not route / correctly to index.php.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is with .htaccess file;

Create a .htaccess file in your web root.

Add the following line...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create/modify .htaccess file in the hosting server.

More info: http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/change-default-page-for-domain.shtml